# Is it possible to connect D- and D+ to an existing USB to FTDI connection?

Tags: pic, usb, ftdi

This maybe a noob question. I already have an ftdi connection on my board, using an FT232 RL connected to a micro USB.

[image]

But, the pic i'm using PIC32MX470F512L has D- and D+ for USB interface. Can i connect it directly to the existing connection of - and + of USB? I know i can use 0 ohm resistance / switch for the signal to go to FTDI or the USB pins of PIC. But would it work? Will it damage anything?

Comment: First thing is define your purpose.

The FTDI chip is used to bridge between a USB interface and a UART interface.
So first question is what is connected to the USB and what is connected to the UART?

Comment: I'm using the UART from the PIC. And i'm planning on using the USB of the PIC too. It's just to give 2 alternatives.

Comment: FTDI is the name of a manufacturer, not a specific chip (they make lots of different ones) or a specific type of interface.

Comment: Don't forget that using the native USB pins will add a lot of software complexity and is generally incompatible with a breakpoint debugger (as far as the host is concerned, the USB device will fail when you hit a breakpoint, and probably have to be re-enumerated after).  If you go that route, make sure the UART pins remain available for use with an *external* USB-UART bridge module.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually switch buses between ports, i.e. if you *either* connect the FTDI chip or your microcontroller, it'd work — just not at the same time.

What you'd avoid is having long "dead end" conductors that you either connect or not using 0 Ω bridges – these would act as capacitive load on the bus. So, keep the part of the bus that's "dead" from the host's perspective as short as possible.

You'll find that USB [switch ICs](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/interface-analog-switches-special-purpose/780?FV=ffe0030c%2C654009e%2C6540925%2C654093d%2C654093e%2C6540b97&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&nstock=1&pageSize=25) exist for this very reason (and are pretty [cheap](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TC7USB40FT-EL/TC7USB40FT-EL-TR-ND/6198966), and run-time switchable!), and use very little power themselves.

Comment: I agree, do not connect both at once, that will lead to bus contention as both parts would respond to queries from the PC. Or the FTDI as slave responding to the PIC part, or similar. Data/clock can be 48 MHz, having stubs would be bad for signal integrity as well.   (Another option might be to have a Reset select header/jumper/DIP switch and put the device that is not being used into a Reset state?)

Comment: @CrossRoads seeing that there tends to be termination involved, you really can't connect them at once (and probably also not in the RESET state); this is not even about confusing slave devices. "Bad for signal integrity": that's what "adds capacitive loading" means, indeed.

Comment: I think that would come down to a careful reading of the datasheet and what happens to the terminations during reset states, but I could see that being a problem too.